# Calling a .bat file from Java in a restricted (Citrix) Environment

Tags: java, windows, maven, batch-file, cmd

I'm not too familiar with programming for the Windows desktop and I'm trying to figure out how to handle calling .bat files from Java. I'm trying to make desktop Java program using Maven run as a jar file execute a bash script in a Citrix virtualization Environment.

The original initial problems was that UNC paths were causing to the batch file to not be found, but I've modified the paths and now I'm able to find the batch file, but cmd.exe is disabled in the Citrix account I'm using, and I worried that there's nothing I can do.

Here's how it works:

1)
User launches program via program.jar file User checks for updates

2)
If updates are found, a new jar file called `program_update.jar` is
   downloaded, and a batch file called `run_update.bat` is copied to the
   main program directory.

3)
From within the java program, the following command is called:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c pushd " + FileName.installation + " && start run_update.bat && popd");`

where `FileName.installation` is a property that has been previous set indicating the home installation directory.

`run_update.bat` runs a loop attempting to replace `program.jar` with `program_update.jar` and show a success/fail message in the command prompt.

---

When I run this in the Citrix environment, I get the following message:

`'run_update.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.`

`The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator.`

At this point, I can click on `run_update.bat` and it runs the operation successfully.

The automatic update called via program.jar works in a normal windows environment with access to cmd.

My questions

- Is my call from java to run `cmd /c <commands>` simply not going to work when cmd.exe is disabled?
- Would renaming run_update.bat to run_update.cmd do any good?
- Any alternative techniques? The batch file is necessary AFAIK because the jar file is replacing itself via the `mv` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem with an alternative technique. It turns out running `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c pushd " + FileName.installation + " && start run_update.bat && popd");` in a Citrix Environment was the problem, becase access to `cmd` is restricted. I rewrote it to use the the Desktop class:

```
File exe = new File(FileName.installation + File.separator + "install_update.bat");

if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(exe);
} else {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c pushd " + FileName.installation + " && start install_update.bat && popd");
}
```